# How to use Amazon Simple Email Service for only verified email sender addresses

Tags: pcp, smtp, amazon, amazon-ses

I have a site running SES for outgoing mail. It works just fine to send out mass email from the domain, but it fails every time I try to share a PCP from a non verified email.

For example if I create a PCP from the main account on civicrm, and I use the SES verified email address, the PCP sharing works just fine.

On the other hand if I create a PCP from my personal email address and try to share the PCP, then the send fails (Amazon SES does not accept unverified email senders).

Is there a way to use mail() instead of AWS SES for this? or a way to allow for the domain to be validated?

Comment: Thanks for your post Brian.  It would help other users if you could explain what the acronyms mean (SES, PCP, AWS).

Comment: Amazon SES is an service offered by Amazon to sent bulk mail. (SES is short for Simple Email Service). Amazon SES is part from a range of services that go by the name AWS (Amazon Web Services).

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup, but I have solved this outside CiviCRM. In CiviCRM, I configured the *mail()* send option. The effect is that the mail is routed by the local Mail Transport Agent. On my system, I use *postfix* for this task.

Postfix can be configured to relay an email to an email service dependent on the email address. Use to do this the **sender_dependent_relayhost_maps** parameter. An example can be found in [this answer on the Unix site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/214125/php-mail-using-postfix-send-out-to-gmail-marked-as-spam).

It is a good practice to send bulk mail with Amazon SES to prevent the email to be marked as spam.

Answer (score 0):

While Kainuk's answer is better, a partial (but simpler to implement) solution is to prevent those emails altogether with the [Outbound Domain Enforcement](https://civicrm.org/extensions/outbound-domain-enforcement) extension.